# i am not able to interact with store method using resource route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-9, resource-router-middleware

I want to store all the records in my database, and I am using the resource route, but when I am submitting my form, data is not going to save in my database and on the other hand, it redirects me to `post.create` route.

These are my Routes, and I am working on Post routes.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController as AdminCategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TagController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController as AdminUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\User\PostController as UserPostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


// USER ROUTES
Route::prefix('')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [UserController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('post', [UserPostController::class, 'index']);
});

// ADMIN ROUTES
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
    // User Routes
    Route::resource('user', AdminUserController::class);
    // Post Routes
    Route::resource('post', PostController::class);
    // Tag Routes
    Route::resource('tag', TagController::class);
    // Category Routes
    Route::resource('category', AdminCategoryController::class);
});
```

**Form**

```
<!-- form start -->
                <form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  @csrf
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title">Post Title</label>
                                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                                @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</p>
                                @endif
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subtitle">Post Sub-Title</label>
                                <input type="text" name="subtitle" class="form-control" id="subtitle" placeholder="SubTitle">
                               @if ($errors->has('subtitle'))
                               <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('subtitle') }}</p>
                               @endif
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="slug">Slug</label>
                                <input type="text" name="slug" class="form-control" id="slug" placeholder="Slug">
                                @if ($errors->has('slug'))
                                <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('slug') }}</p>
                                @endif
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="image">File input</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="image">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Choose file</label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              @if ($errors->has('image'))
                              <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</p>
                              @endif
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="form-check-input" id="status">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="status">Publish</label>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                        <label for="title">Write Post Body Here</label>
                        <textarea id="summernote" name="body"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('body'))
                        <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('body') }}</p>
                        @endif
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>    
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->

                </form>
```

**This is my PostController, and I am working on Store Method**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'subtitle' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        $post = new post;

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $file_name = time().'_'.$request->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $file_path =  $request->file('image')->storeAs('uploads',$file_name,'public');
        $post->image = $file_path;
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->save();

        return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

run `php artisan route:list` command on console, and check if post routes are showing in the routes list.

Comment: i have done this and you can see i am using in form action='{{ route('post.store') }}' but it is not going to store and redirect me to route.create route